# Rails store/show values in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, session, jruby

I am working on a rails project that takes user input.  I want to be able to show the user values in the url and i am having trouble how to do this.

For example, I retrieve an input "limit"

```
limit = params[:limit] (where :limit = 10)
```

And I want the url to be something like this

www.someurl.com/myproject/limit="10" or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the URL you're looking for is www.someurl.com/myproject?limit=10

Assuming you have a myproject path, you can:

```
link_to "Link Text", myproject_path(limit: 10)
```

In your controller, you'll then:

```
limit = params[:limit]
```

If you'd like to set a default value for limit you can use:

```
limit = params[:limit] || 10
```

or

```
limit = params.fetch(:limit, 10)
```

Comment: thank you. what would be the correct way to route this then?          No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"patient_record", :limit=>10}

Comment: appears you need to have an ID to use the show action. or use the index action if you want to show more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a perfect use case for a get request with parameters. If for example you have a url helper called `myproject_path` that returns the path "/myproject", then could you do something like this:

```
myproject_path(:limit => 10) # this returns "/myproject?limit=10"
```

You can now access this value as you do in your question (through `params[:limit]`)

Hope this answers your question?